# What is the purpose of this grammar production in "Precedence Climbing Method"?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I saw an example of the so called "Precedence Climbing Method" for representing operator precedence in a formal grammar on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser).

It gives the following grammar as an example:

```
expression ::= equality-expression
equality-expression ::= additive-expression ( ( '==' | '!=' ) additive-expression ) *
additive-expression ::= multiplicative-expression ( ( '+' | '-' ) multiplicative-expression ) *
multiplicative-expression ::= primary ( ( '*' | '/' ) primary ) *
primary ::= '(' expression ')' | NUMBER | VARIABLE | '-' primary
```

I don't understand what the purpose of the `'-' primary` at the end of the last production is. Can anyone explain why it is constructed this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unary minus, which binds more tightly than multiplicative operators:

```
-a * 7
```

(Not that it makes much difference in that case.)